# In computer logic in python, does the distribution law work?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I think the results of if condition 1 and if condition 2 are the same. but it isn't.

```
a= [[20200101, 'batman'], [20200102, 'superman'], [20200102, 20200102], [20200103, 20200103]]

#if condition 1
for item in a:
    if (item[1] != 'batman') and (item[1] != item[0]):
        print(item)
print('div')

#if condition 2
for item in a:
    if item[1] != ('batman' and item[0]):
        print(item)
```

**result**

```
[20200102, 'superman']
div
[20200101, 'batman']
[20200102, 'superman']
```

the Result of if condition 1 is what I expected.
I think I should relearn logic that I have forgotten since 2015.

Comment: `('batman' and item[0])` will always evaluate to `item[0]` so you are always testing `item[1] != item[0]`

Comment: What you are using isn't a law; at best, it's an idiom in English (though you would say "item one does not equal batman **or** item zero", not **and**.

Comment: What do you expect ('batman' and item[0]) evaluates to?

Comment: A distribution law would be something like `a and (b or c) == a and b or a and c`.

Comment: `!=` does not distribute over `and`, neither in Python nor mathematics.

Comment: Is this even related to mathematics/logic, or simply the way Python is designed?

Comment: What "distribution law" are you referring to?

Comment: Wasn't bulling you…just trying to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: HemingwayHong: if you see actual bullying, best to notify the moderators of it by flagging them. But I have to agree with @martineau, in that I don't see instances of bullying in the comments above. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm joking, guys.... I'm sorry... No offense. I'm new to Stackoverflow. I'm not going to do this again. Thank you everybody. Thank you. Good morning from South Korea!

Answer (score 1):

`x and y` checks if `x` evaluates as true and if it does it yields `y` (and otherwise `x`). Take the following examples:

```
>>> 1 and []
[]
>>> [] and 1
[]
```

In your example, since `'batman'` is true this always yields `item[0]`, so you check only whether `item[0] != item[1]`. If you want to shorten that check you can use:

```
if 'batman' != item[1] != item[0]:
    ...
```

Chained comparisons are expanded as check the left comparison `and` the right one. More readable might be to use a `tuple`:

```
if item[1] not in ('batman', item[0]):
    ...
```

Comment: In your last code block, you used set notation, rather than list notation. Is that intentional? I think it's likely to be confusing and hinders performance, because constructing a set is more complex than constructing a list.

Comment: @GregSchmit I doubt that performance is affected in any case here, since only two items are involved. If at all a `tuple` should be used because a list allocates some extra space; but maybe this is even optimized away in popular implementations of Python. And if you see a `in` check why would you be concerned which type of brackets that follow? The internal workings are different but the result is the same. The only that matters is hashability so I will change this to a tuple check indeed.

Comment: A tuple is better. For two elements hashing is slower than just checking both.

Comment: @GregSchmit For your information, on CPython 3.7, list literals used as temporary objects in comparisons are optimized to tuples instead. Check `import dis; dis.dis('1 in [0, 1, 2]')`.

Comment: @kaya3 In general this might be true, but I guess most implementations of Python (at least CPython) optimize this at various stages. For example in CPython string objects store their hash value once computed so it can be reused. `int` objects just hash to the very same value, so that's trivial too. So effectively no hashing will occur beyond the first time. In addition to that, compile-time constants are interned (e.g. the `'batman'` string) and before comparing the hash value, items are compared for identity. So for the OP's specific example, the check won't attempt to compute a single hash.

Comment: @a_guest No need to be defensive, `tuple` is fine too, the set notation just looked odd and I wasn't sure if you thought it was faster than list/tuple, because it is slower.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Because using a list/tuple is linear in complexity WRT number of elements, but building a set is also minimally linear (because it has to go through the provided elements), with extra work of either grabbing pre-processed hash or calculating it for each element in the set. While you could argue it's minimal for this because it's 2 elements, this is clearly a toy example.